# stub_request method loses the .to_return portion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this stub registered in my spec:

```
stub_request(:post, "https://sandbox.usaepay.com/gate").
          with(:body => {"UMaccount"=>nil, "UMaccounttype"=>nil, "UMaddcustomer"=>nil, "UMallowPartialAuth"=>nil, "UMamount"=>"123.45 ", "UMauthCode"=>nil, "UMauthExpireDays"=>nil, "UMauxonus"=>nil, "UMbillamount"=>nil, "UMbillcity"=>nil, "UMbillcompany"=>nil, "UMbillcountry"=>nil, "UMbillfname"=>nil, "UMbilllname"=>nil, "UMbillphone"=>nil, "UMbillsourcekey"=>nil, "UMbillstate"=>nil, "UMbillstreet"=>nil, "UMbillstreet2"=>nil, "UMbilltax"=>nil, "UMbillzip"=>nil, "UMcard"=>"4000100011112224", "UMcardauth"=>nil, "UMcardpresent"=>"false", "UMcavv"=>nil, "UMcheckformat"=>nil, "UMcheckimageback"=>nil, "UMcheckimageencoding"=>"base64", "UMcheckimagefront"=>nil, "UMchecknum"=>nil, "UMclerk"=>nil, "UMcommand"=>"sale", "UMcomments"=>nil, "UMcontactless"=>nil, "UMcurrency"=>nil, "UMcustemail"=>nil, "UMcustid"=>nil, "UMcustreceipt"=>nil, "UMcustreceiptname"=>nil, "UMcvv2"=>" 123 ", "UMdescription"=>"Payment for Job #2015011", "UMdiscount"=>nil, "UMdlnum"=>nil, "UMdlstate"=>nil, "UMdukpt"=>nil, "UMeci"=>nil, "UMemail"=>nil, "UMepcCode"=>nil, "UMexpir"=>"0919", "UMexpire"=>nil, "UMfax"=>nil, "UMhash"=>"s/201611182063/8bfd2a8b4f07fc07d63e0f7f652df1295e96bb50/n", "UMifAuthExpired"=>nil, "UMignoreDuplicate"=>nil, "UMinventorylocation"=>nil, "UMinvoice"=>nil, "UMip"=>nil, "UMkey"=>"_MobxK18CP42k6RfKjYnl7yve7W4dr4X", "UMmagstripe"=>nil, "UMmagsupport"=>nil, "UMname"=>"Some Guy", "UMnontaxable"=>nil, "UMnumleft"=>nil, "UMorderid"=>"2015011", "UMpares"=>nil, "UMponum"=>nil, "UMrecurring"=>nil, "UMrefNum"=>nil, "UMresttable"=>nil, "UMrouting"=>nil, "UMsaveCard"=>nil, "UMschedule"=>nil, "UMshipcity"=>nil, "UMshipcompany"=>nil, "UMshipcountry"=>nil, "UMshipfname"=>nil, "UMshiplname"=>nil, "UMshipphone"=>nil, "UMshipping"=>nil, "UMshipstate"=>nil, "UMshipstreet"=>nil, "UMshipstreet2"=>nil, "UMshipzip"=>nil, "UMsignature"=>nil, "UMsoftware"=>"USAePay RUBY API v. 1.0.2", "UMssn"=>nil, "UMstart"=>nil, "UMstreet"=>"1234 Anywhere Lane", "UMsubtotal"=>nil, "UMtax"=>nil, "UMtermtype"=>nil, "UMtestmode"=>nil, "UMtimeout"=>"45", "UMtip"=>nil, "UMtranterm"=>nil, "UMwebsite"=>nil, "UMxid"=>nil, "UMzip"=>"90210"},
               :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
          to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

And when I run the test, I get the following error message:

You can stub this request with the following snippet:

```
stub_request(:post, "https://sandbox.usaepay.com/gate").
  with(:body => {"UMaccount"=>nil, "UMaccounttype"=>nil, "UMaddcustomer"=>nil, "UMallowPartialAuth"=>nil, "UMamount"=>"123.45 ", "UMauthCode"=>nil, "UMauthExpireDays"=>nil, "UMauxonus"=>nil, "UMbillamount"=>nil, "UMbillcity"=>nil, "UMbillcompany"=>nil, "UMbillcountry"=>nil, "UMbillfname"=>nil, "UMbilllname"=>nil, "UMbillphone"=>nil, "UMbillsourcekey"=>nil, "UMbillstate"=>nil, "UMbillstreet"=>nil, "UMbillstreet2"=>nil, "UMbilltax"=>nil, "UMbillzip"=>nil, "UMcard"=>"4000100011112224", "UMcardauth"=>nil, "UMcardpresent"=>"false", "UMcavv"=>nil, "UMcheckformat"=>nil, "UMcheckimageback"=>nil, "UMcheckimageencoding"=>"base64", "UMcheckimagefront"=>nil, "UMchecknum"=>nil, "UMclerk"=>nil, "UMcommand"=>"sale", "UMcomments"=>nil, "UMcontactless"=>nil, "UMcurrency"=>nil, "UMcustemail"=>nil, "UMcustid"=>nil, "UMcustreceipt"=>nil, "UMcustreceiptname"=>nil, "UMcvv2"=>" 123 ", "UMdescription"=>"Payment for Job #2015011", "UMdiscount"=>nil, "UMdlnum"=>nil, "UMdlstate"=>nil, "UMdukpt"=>nil, "UMeci"=>nil, "UMemail"=>nil, "UMepcCode"=>nil, "UMexpir"=>"0919", "UMexpire"=>nil, "UMfax"=>nil, "UMhash"=>"s/2016111820672/b0175954f0ce709aa2899e45a1329c6fb63905d5/n", "UMifAuthExpired"=>nil, "UMignoreDuplicate"=>nil, "UMinventorylocation"=>nil, "UMinvoice"=>nil, "UMip"=>nil, "UMkey"=>"_MobxK18CP42k6RfKjYnl7yve7W4dr4X", "UMmagstripe"=>nil, "UMmagsupport"=>nil, "UMname"=>"Some guy", "UMnontaxable"=>nil, "UMnumleft"=>nil, "UMorderid"=>"2015011", "UMpares"=>nil, "UMponum"=>nil, "UMrecurring"=>nil, "UMrefNum"=>nil, "UMresttable"=>nil, "UMrouting"=>nil, "UMsaveCard"=>nil, "UMschedule"=>nil, "UMshipcity"=>nil, "UMshipcompany"=>nil, "UMshipcountry"=>nil, "UMshipfname"=>nil, "UMshiplname"=>nil, "UMshipphone"=>nil, "UMshipping"=>nil, "UMshipstate"=>nil, "UMshipstreet"=>nil, "UMshipstreet2"=>nil, "UMshipzip"=>nil, "UMsignature"=>nil, "UMsoftware"=>"USAePay RUBY API v. 1.0.2", "UMssn"=>nil, "UMstart"=>nil, "UMstreet"=>"1234 Anywhere Lane", "UMsubtotal"=>nil, "UMtax"=>nil, "UMtermtype"=>nil, "UMtestmode"=>nil, "UMtimeout"=>"45", "UMtip"=>nil, "UMtranterm"=>nil, "UMwebsite"=>nil, "UMxid"=>nil, "UMzip"=>"90210"},
       :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

registered request stubs:

stub_request(:post, "https://sandbox.usaepay.com/gate").
  with(:body => {"UMaccount"=>nil, "UMaccounttype"=>nil, "UMaddcustomer"=>nil, "UMallowPartialAuth"=>nil, "UMamount"=>"123.45 ", "UMauthCode"=>nil, "UMauthExpireDays"=>nil, "UMauxonus"=>nil, "UMbillamount"=>nil, "UMbillcity"=>nil, "UMbillcompany"=>nil, "UMbillcountry"=>nil, "UMbillfname"=>nil, "UMbilllname"=>nil, "UMbillphone"=>nil, "UMbillsourcekey"=>nil, "UMbillstate"=>nil, "UMbillstreet"=>nil, "UMbillstreet2"=>nil, "UMbilltax"=>nil, "UMbillzip"=>nil, "UMcard"=>"4000100011112224", "UMcardauth"=>nil, "UMcardpresent"=>"false", "UMcavv"=>nil, "UMcheckformat"=>nil, "UMcheckimageback"=>nil, "UMcheckimageencoding"=>"base64", "UMcheckimagefront"=>nil, "UMchecknum"=>nil, "UMclerk"=>nil, "UMcommand"=>"sale", "UMcomments"=>nil, "UMcontactless"=>nil, "UMcurrency"=>nil, "UMcustemail"=>nil, "UMcustid"=>nil, "UMcustreceipt"=>nil, "UMcustreceiptname"=>nil, "UMcvv2"=>" 123 ", "UMdescription"=>"Payment for Job #2015011", "UMdiscount"=>nil, "UMdlnum"=>nil, "UMdlstate"=>nil, "UMdukpt"=>nil, "UMeci"=>nil, "UMemail"=>nil, "UMepcCode"=>nil, "UMexpir"=>"0919", "UMexpire"=>nil, "UMfax"=>nil, "UMhash"=>"s/201611182063/8bfd2a8b4f07fc07d63e0f7f652df1295e96bb50/n", "UMifAuthExpired"=>nil, "UMignoreDuplicate"=>nil, "UMinventorylocation"=>nil, "UMinvoice"=>nil, "UMip"=>nil, "UMkey"=>"_MobxK18CP42k6RfKjYnl7yve7W4dr4X", "UMmagstripe"=>nil, "UMmagsupport"=>nil, "UMname"=>" Some Guy", "UMnontaxable"=>nil, "UMnumleft"=>nil, "UMorderid"=>"2015011", "UMpares"=>nil, "UMponum"=>nil, "UMrecurring"=>nil, "UMrefNum"=>nil, "UMresttable"=>nil, "UMrouting"=>nil, "UMsaveCard"=>nil, "UMschedule"=>nil, "UMshipcity"=>nil, "UMshipcompany"=>nil, "UMshipcountry"=>nil, "UMshipfname"=>nil, "UMshiplname"=>nil, "UMshipphone"=>nil, "UMshipping"=>nil, "UMshipstate"=>nil, "UMshipstreet"=>nil, "UMshipstreet2"=>nil, "UMshipzip"=>nil, "UMsignature"=>nil, "UMsoftware"=>"USAePay RUBY API v. 1.0.2", "UMssn"=>nil, "UMstart"=>nil, "UMstreet"=>"1234 Anywhere Lane", "UMsubtotal"=>nil, "UMtax"=>nil, "UMtermtype"=>nil, "UMtestmode"=>nil, "UMtimeout"=>"45", "UMtip"=>nil, "UMtranterm"=>nil, "UMwebsite"=>nil, "UMxid"=>nil, "UMzip"=>"90210"},
       :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'})
```

Note how the registered stubs doesn't have any mention of the ".to_return" portion - despite it being clearly defined in my stub_request

Has anyone experienced this issue with Rspec before?

rspec and dependency versions used:

```
rspec (3.5.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-core (3.5.4)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-rails (3.5.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-support (3.5.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `UMhash` parameter is different on every request, you have to define a stub that ignores it or ensure it's the same on each test request. E.g. by using timecop to freeze time, if the UMhash depends on time.

`to_return` is missing from the registered stubs, since it doesn't matter for matching requests. to_return is only used to declare the stubbed response.

Most likely you will have to define `to_return` that matches some real response.